# Can this double picker be achieved by a web app (not a native app)?

Tags: web-app, input, html, mobile-web, jquerymobile

[image: Can this double picker be achieved by a web app (not a native app)?]

Can this double picker be achieved by a web app in HTML (not a native app)?

Comment: The simple answer is that from a UI POV, nearly any native interaction can be emulated in a web app via JS, CSS and HTML. The more complex answer is to ask the question "when is it more appropriate to invest in emulating a native app vs. embracing the fact that it's a web app?" The answer to that will vary.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes it can**.

Take a look at [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/).  The example below is from my iPhone in Safari (HTML5 app).

[image]

Comment: Thanks John! It seems not built into jQuery mobile, even the mobiscroll.com plugin does not provide a double picker :(

Comment: We tried jQuery mobile for a while but ended up switching to Sencha.  I wish we did it 6 months ago.  It's not perfect, but makes dev work much simpler.

Comment: jQuery mobile is mean to be a universal UI layer regardless of platform. Sencha tends to borrow more directly from iOS in emulating the controls.

Comment: IMHO, Sencha is perfect if the team is fairly happy with the stuff out-of-the-box (it is fairly robust). jQuery is preferred if there's going to be a lot of roll-your-own solutions. I always prefer the out-of-the-box option from a dev standpoint but realize that from a UX POV, more often than not, there's a lot of rolling-your-own.